# Yii why many jquery statements lose their effectiveness after Ajax call including the following new issue with select all in ChckBoxList:

Tags: jquery, checkbox, yii, checkboxlist

This happened with me many times, I managed to fix most of them, but here again another new issue:

Using Checkboxlist there is a checkbox called select all after an ajax operation that box when clicked stops selecting all other checkboxes as it was supposed to do. So how do I refresh it?

```
<?php
        $filterList = array(
            'first' => 'first option',
            'second' => 'second option',
            'third' => 'third option',

        );
        $htmlOptions = array(
            'checkAll'=>'Select All',
            'separator' => ' ',
            'template' => '{input}&nbsp;{label}<br/>'
//            'template' => '<tr><td >{label}</td><td>{input}</td></tr>'
        );
        echo CHtml::checkBoxList('filters', array('1'), $filterList, $htmlOptions)
        ?>
```

The Following is the generated Jquery

```
jQuery('#filters_all').click(function() {
    jQuery("input[name='filters\[\]']").attr('checked', this.checked);
});
jQuery("input[name='filters\[\]']").click(function() {
    jQuery('#filters_all').attr('checked', !jQuery("input[name='filters\[\]']:not(:checked)").length);
});
jQuery('#filters_all').attr('checked', !jQuery("input[name='filters\[\]']:not(:checked)").length);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you're binding the click event handler using the `.click()` function, and that as a result of your AJAX call, you're replacing the element.

Either don't replace the element as part of your AJAX call, or use the [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) (jQuery 1.7+) or [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) (prior to jQuery 1.7) functions to assign the event handler to an element that isn't going to be replaced, like so:

```
$('body').on('click', 'selector', function(e) {
    // select all checkboxes here
});
```

or

```
$('body').delegate('selector', 'click', function(e) {
    // select all checkboxes here
});
```

Comment: I've added the generated jquery code, cause I didn't understand your assumption, thanks for ur interest, hope you can elaborate more based on that edit